# Flash Builder or Flash Professional?

Tags: actionscript, starling-framework

I wanted to learn action script for mobile development.Me and my friends are planning to make some Mobile games.What tools should we buy ?

Adobe Flash Builder Premium 
Adobe Flash Professional

Comment: Flash Builder is geared towards developers where as Flash Developers is better suited for designers/animators/asset creation in general. You can code within Flash Professional and the code editor is a bit better than it used to be, but it doesn't compare to other IDEs out there. There are alternatives to Flash Builder such as ItelliJ IDEA and FDT. You should also check out free/opensource platforms like [FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org/)(Windows only so far) and explore [HaXe](http://haxe.org/)/[OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/showcase/)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have mentioned Starling framework in your tags, so I assume you will be using it in your games. Thus you can effectively use Flash Develop as it is free and stable IDE, which will let you build your Starling project for PC and mobile very easily.

Flash Builder is more Flex-bussiness app oriented and Adobe Flash Professional is not particulary good at code editing, because it's primary purpose is to allow designers quickly create flash apps.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with GuardianX for his comments on Flash Builder and Flash Professional.

As an IDE alternative I definitely recommend [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). It gives better performance and you can do everything you can do on Flash Builder (Packaging etc.)